# How to know what page is calling admin-ajax.php?

Tags: ajax, uploads, file-manager

The original goal is this:
all users can add and remove images from the page on front end, but, they can only see their own images.

When in the admin part of the website, administrators should see all images, from every user. (only administrators have access to the admin part of the website).

So far, I have the following code:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments' );
function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {
    global $current_user, $pagenow;
    $is_attachment_request = ($wp_query_obj->get('post_type')=='attachment');   
    if( !$is_attachment_request )
        return; 
    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return; 
    if( !in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) )
        return;
    if(basename(get_page_template()) === 'upload.php')
        return;
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) 
        return;
    $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID );   
    return;
}
```

However, `$pagenow` always returns `admin-ajax.php`, no matter on what page it's beeing called, and `basename(get_page_template())` always returns only home URL. `$wp_query_obj` doesn't have any usefull information in it.

How can I check if the user is on upload.php, or on another page on the site?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your users definitely on a page called `upload.php`? Or is that in reference to a WordPress core file? If your user is on the front end, the page they will be making the request from is unlikely to be the aforementioned unless you have created an `upload.php` file yourself that is requested directly. Can you elaborate...

Comment: No, users are not on that page.
Users can upload images on their profile page, eg: mysite.com/author/admin. They can open media selector I've enabled using javascript. On this page, everyone should see only their own images. But, if an administrator goes to the upload.php page, they should see all images from all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching the internet, and I found out about this

```
strtolower( wp_get_referer() );
```

So I was able to place simple if statement and test what page called the admin-ajax.

`if (strpos($referrer, 'upload.php') === false) { ... }`

Comment: That's a client-supplied header though, and can be faked by the client, if you're using it for anything security related.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up